# How to customize the mouse cursor when over a specific X11 window?

Tags: x11, remmina

My main system has 1080p displays but I often connect to a 4K laptop via VNC under Remmina. When connected and the mouse pointer is over the Remmina window, the cursor expands in size by a factor of 4 and looks huge.

Is there some way to customize the appearance of the cursor when over the Remmina window, even if that means losing the contextual visual cues for the current mouse position (text, links, etc)?  Essentially, when the mouse cursor is over the Remmina window, the idea was:

1. to shrink the cursor to its normal size
2. failing the above, to forcefully set a mouse cursor

Is this possible at all?